# Calling web API with route attribute using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a web API controller

```
    public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostAction(int id, Student student)
    {
        return Ok("This is message");
    }

}
```

I can call PostAction method using JQuery

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            var obj = { 'name': 'alex' };
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("PostAction","Default",new {id=3,httproute=true})',
                    data: obj
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    alert("success: " + data);
                })
                .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error: " + xhr.responseText);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Generated url is: /api/default/3'

Now if I put routing attribute on controller

```
    [Route("api/default")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
```

how should I call APIs using Url.Action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't apply the Route attribute to the controller, instead you apply it to an action method.

Also there is no point in applying an a route pattern which matches with the default route pattern url. But if you are using attribute routing to give a nice url pattern to your action method, you can specify the route name as well which you can use with the  `HttpRouteUrl` helper method.

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/default2",Name = "MyApi")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostAction(int id, Student student)
    {
        return Ok("This is message");
    }
}
```

and in your razor view you can do this.

```
<script>
   var url = "@Url.HttpRouteUrl("MyApi", new { id = 3 })";
</script>
```